# Grid leaving extra space between column definitions

Tags: wpf, grid, columndefinition

I have a custom button with a custom defined template. In the template i'm using grid definitions to sort the content of a `Rectangle`, `Canvas` and `Label`.

Here's the template:

```
<ControlTemplate
    TargetType="{x:Type l:UXButton}">
    <Border
        Name="TEMP_Container"
        Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
        Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
        BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
        BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
        CornerRadius="{TemplateBinding CornerRadius}"
        FlowDirection="{Binding Converter={StaticResource LocalizedFlowConverter}}">
        <Grid
            Name="TEMP_ContentContainer"
            Background="Blue">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition
                    Name="ColumnIcon"
                    Width="{Binding ActualHeight, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Border}}}" />
                <ColumnDefinition
                    Name="ColumnSpace"
                    Width="auto" />
                <ColumnDefinition
                    Name="ColumnContent"
                    Width="auto" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Rectangle
                Name="TEMP_Icon"
                Grid.Column="0"
                Margin="0"
                Fill="{TemplateBinding Foreground}">
                <Rectangle.OpacityMask>
                    <VisualBrush
                        Stretch="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=l:UXButton}, Path=Stretch}"
                        Visual="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=l:UXButton}, Path=IconSource}" />
                </Rectangle.OpacityMask>
            </Rectangle>
            <Canvas
                Name="TEMP_Space"
                Grid.Column="1"
                Margin="0"
                Width="{TemplateBinding Spacing}" />
            <Label
                Name="TEMP_Content"
                Grid.Column="2"
                Margin="0"
                Padding="0"
                HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
                Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}">
                <TextBlock
                    Margin="0"
                    Padding="0"
                    Text="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                    TextDecorations="{TemplateBinding TextDecorations}" />
            </Label>
        </Grid>
    </Border>
</ControlTemplate>
```

And here's the result:

[image]

As you can see the grid is leaving an extra space (blue) between the `Canvas` (red) and `Rectangle` (green) which i can't seem to figure why! I even tried using static values for the column width but it didn't help. I also used the `XAML debugging tools` and it seems to be part of the `Grid`.

Where is this space coming from?

Comment: We're supposed to be looking at the gap between the green and red?  If you make the third column * width rather than auto, what happens?

Comment: Maybe that should be a stackpanel rather than grid?

Comment: Yes the blue gap is the problem + setting width to anything including `*` won't change a thing. And maybe you're right i should use a stackpanel but that won't fix the problem with `Grid` anywhere else where i have to use a `Grid`!

Comment: The space is because your grid column isn't being allowed to contract to fit the width of contents. why would you use this technique anywhere you use a grid? If you want a container to size itself to a bunch of contents then this is exactly what the stackpanel is designed for.

Comment: Why do you have a canvas there at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out to be a bug. Cleaning up `bin` and `obj` folders and simply doing a `Rebuild` fixed it. It must have been a `Resource` that got stuck somewhere in the middle.

Answer (score 0):

I think the simple way to "fix" what you have but retain that grid as you have it is wrap it in another.

That way it should centralise and shrink.
Unless you have something sets the grid's width.

Comment: Nope, that didn't fix it. It turned out to be a bug actually. I used the same example in a different project and it worked fine.